# Why does auto-numbering take over my numbering?

Tags: support, markdown

I am numbering the following list from zero to three:

1. This is numbered zero.
2. This is numbered one.
3. This is numbered two.
4. This is numbered three.

Why does it show up as numbered one through four in the post?  How can I override this behaviour?

A related discussion can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/numbers-after-paragraph-breaks-turn-into-1s); however, it does not seem to have a solution for this problem.

Comment: Did you read [this answer on the thread you linked to](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1573/264)? It describes the cause and solutions. The cause is the Markdown formatting engine. You can force Markdown to not parse what you're doing as an ordered list so that your desired content is preserved.

Comment: You can also use HTML directly, e.g. `<ol start="0">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ol>`

Comment: Thanks, I missed that solution.  I read the first half of that post, as well as the "Not anymore!" solution below it, but somehow missed the second half of that post.  Again, thanks.  Can I close this question?